# Submitting Data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit, flot

Using numerical data that a user inputs, I am trying to send that data to a function that uses jQuery's FLOT, which then graphs the points. When I click submit, the alert function returns "NaN", but proceeds to graph the other data. What would I be doing wrong? Do I need to put the inputs in a form?

```
<input type="number" id="txt_name">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick=" return hello();">
<script type="text/javascript">

var d1 = [];
function hello(){

$(function() {


    var x=document.getElementById('txt_name');
    var y=parseInt(x);
    alert(y);
    d1.push([x,x]);
    d1.push([x+5,x+5]);

    var d2 = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]];

    // A null signifies separate line segments

    var d3 = [[0, 12], [7, 12], null, [7, 2.5], [12, 2.5]];

    $.plot("#placeholder", [ d1, d2, d3 ]);

    // Add the Flot version string to the footer


});
}
</script>
```

Comment: would be nice if you could accept any of the answers below.

Answer (score 4):

You have a problem with your code on this line:

```
var x=document.getElementById('txt_name');
```

The problem here is that document.getElementById('txt_name') returns an `Element` object not a value that user entered. To grab a value you need to invoke `value` property like this:

```
var x=document.getElementById('txt_name').value;
```

Fixed your code:

```
<input type="number" id="txt_name">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick=" return hello();">
<script type="text/javascript">

var d1 = [];
function hello(){

$(function() {


    var x=document.getElementById('txt_name').value;
    var y=parseInt(x);
    alert(y);
    d1.push([x,x]);
    d1.push([x+5,x+5]);

    var d2 = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]];

    // A null signifies separate line segments

    var d3 = [[0, 12], [7, 12], null, [7, 2.5], [12, 2.5]];

    $.plot("#placeholder", [ d1, d2, d3 ]);

    // Add the Flot version string to the footer


});
}
</script>
```

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties).

Comment: It will probably help the OP to pair the snippet with some explanation, though. What did you change and why?

Answer (score 3):

You have to get the value from the input

```
var x=document.getElementById('txt_name').value;
var y=parseInt(x, 10);
```